# Why can't I use FindElementByXPath on this table from a website?

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am currently working with webscraping on vba using selenium and chromedriver.

I log in a website (the website is, unfortunately, unreacheable due to a login necessity, but it's  https://monitoring.csisolar.com/login), and within the main page, there is a general table with a bunch of info.

I used "inspect element" and identified the table object as in the image:

[print of the found element, the table is highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EEkh.png)

When I select "copy xpath", I get this: "//*[@id="mCSB_67_container"]/table"

Naturally, I set the command like this:

```
Set tabela = driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id="mCSB_67_container"]/table") 'Seleciona a tabela pelo java

If tabela Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Não encontrado"
Else
    tabela.AsTable().ToExcel (ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)) 'Cola a tabela na planilha (aba) onde está o botão
End If
```

but nothing is printed on excell.

I did the same thing in other similar sites (solarweb.com) and it went very well, but the table object had a id and class defined, while the one above has no attributes named (as seen on the print)

I know this question is not very clarified, but please comment below if there's something that can help you understand and I will gladly edit my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is being tried on the question does not work because that table element is a **dynamic object**, so it's "id" and "class" attributes are not constant and cannot be referecend.
So, thanks to @Prophet and @David M, I discovered that I should be looking for a static reference instead, a part of the site's interface that wasnt dynamic, and then use that to reference said table.

The element I used was the division that contained the element, which had an ID of "plantList". Here's a screenshot of how I found this element:

[In red, an arrow pointing to the table element, and in green, an arrow pointing to the statc element that I used to reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EIoD.jpg)

From this point on, I just make my way through every other element until I reached the table. the final line is something like this:

```
Set canadian = driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id=""plantList""]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/table") 'Seleciona a tabela pelo java

If canadian Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Não Encontrado"
Else
    canadian.AsTable().ToExcel (ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)) 'Cola a tabela na planilha (aba) onde está o botão
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Whatever is under the hood is creating dynamic ids. Your goal is to find selectors that don't change. Then use them to navigate down the DOM until you get to your table. In your small excerpt I don't see anything that's screaming unique id that never changes. If you only have one table visible you could just find it like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("table"));
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, it's not the only table. I may try to find a static thing and make my way through "tabs". Is there any specific thing I should be looking to find this ? If I post the entire html thing does it help ? (and is it safe to do so ?)

Answer (score 1):

`mCSB_67_container` seems to be a dynamically created `id` value i.e. this is not a fixed `id` value.
I'm not sure (need to see the actual page with dev tools), but you can try using this XPath instead:

```
Set tabela = driver.FindElementByXPath("//div[contains(@class,'mCustomScrollBox']//table")
```

Comment: This is YOUR code line but with possibly correct XPath locator.

Comment: You asked why your XPath doesn't work, I tried to explain + to give better locator

Comment: I understand, but what changed on this locator ? I just want to understand why it's better

Comment: I wrote that you are basing your locator on id that seems to be dynamic. this is why you can not find element matching this locator since the id is changing each time. I tried to base the xpath on class name of the parent element that looks to be fixed. I'm not sure it is fixed and not sure it is unique since YOU didn't provide the link to that page / credentials to login there.

Comment: Oh I see. if I find a fixed element and reference using this line then it will select the table, right ? I will probably look for this solution since both of you guys suggested it. If ir wokrs I'll come back

Comment: Not exactly. If there are several tables there his locator will select the first table on the page while my will select table inside specific parent element.

Comment: So, "//div" means you are looking for <div> elements, "contains" is a specification to look for divs that contain that specific class ? Just to be sure. The last "//table" part I understand already

Comment: My xpath literally means: element with tag name "div" that contains class name "mCustomScrollBox" and after it element with tag name "table"

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, it is hard locate the element,
if it is static table and dynamically updating values page. better right click and copy xpath given by chrome. that works efficiently. instead writing looping logic.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8zru.jpg)

Comment: I tried that, as I told on the question, but it didn't work.